# how to use different layout for different pages in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i know application.html.erb is the default for every page .i want to use a different layout when user login .i mean the dashboard after login should be of different layout rather than the default one(application.html.erb).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create new layout eg `app/views/layouts/dunno.html.erb`. Use in controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  layout 'dunno'
end
```

or per action

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render layout: 'dunno'
  end
end
```

see [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout) for details

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in application controller, add this code, I am assuming that you are using `devise`

```
layout :layout_by_resource

def layout_by_resource
  user_signed_in? ? "my_custom_layout" : "application"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your application_controller.rb file do this, hope it helps.

```
 layout :set_layout
 def set_layout
    if current_user
      'dashboard_layout'
    else
      'default_layout'
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Details about layouts can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html).

> Using a different layout in the action render call
>
> If most of your actions use the same layout, it makes perfect sense to
>   define a controller-wide layout as described above. Sometimes you'll
>   have exceptions where one action wants to use a different layout than
>   the rest of the controller. You can do this by passing a :layout
>   option to the render call. For example:

```
class WeblogController < ActionController::Base
  layout "weblog_standard"

  def help
    render action: "help", layout: "help"
  end
end
```

> This will override the controller-wide “weblog_standard” layout, and will render the help
>   action with the “help” layout instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *devise* gem, and your goal is to use another layout within *devise* controllers, have a look at their [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts)

Answer (score 0):

i wanted two different layouts before signin and after signin,so i have implemented using below code where `application_controller` changes the layout if user is signed_in else uses different layout....
**if you are using devise ,dont forget to add layouts in views/layouts**

**in application_controller.rb**

```
layout :layout_by_resource
    def layout_by_resource
     unless user_signed_in?
      Rails.logger.info "===========Setting layout as views/layouts/auth.html.erb"
       'auth'
     else
      Rails.logger.info "===========Setting layout as views/layouts/blue.html.erb"
       'basic'
     end
   end
```